# Excel adds equal sign to SOME lines

Tags: excel, text, excel-2010

I have a .csv file that I generated with a program. And when I open it with Excel. Some lines get an equal sign '=' added in front of them, which causes the excel file to write #NAME? in the cell. But some don't...

Some of the lines:

these lines

```
+P moc maksymalna skumulowana; + P moc maksymalna skumulowana  M717
```

becomes into

```
=+P moc maksymalna skumulowana; =+ P moc maksymalna skumulowana  M717
```

therefore it's #NAME?

But this line

```
+ P moc maksymalna w OR, M1
```

Remains fine.

There are many more. Some with a '-' in the front, some with a '+'. Some have a space after the sign, some don't. Some have a text like "M1" in them, that could be treated like a cell, some don't.
And some of them get a '=' added in front of them, and some of them don't. Randomly. With no connection.
I can't find anything specific that is causing it. Anyone ever faced a problem like this before?

P.S. I'm not polish, just making some localization files translated by someone else.

Comment: Excels ALWAYS expects a formula when a cell entry starts with an operator (e.g. +). To avoid too many error messages, it corrects entries like that automatically. The `#NAME?` error means a name referring to a cell/group of cells was expected after the + operator. Put a ' (apostrophe symbol) before the + to make it a text entry.

Comment: I already provided and example where a space after the + doesn't do any good and it still get's a = glued in the front.

Comment: I updated my comment :)

Comment: But why some of the lines don't get this error?
for example

"- R całkowita energia bierna T1"

"+ P moc maksymalna w OR, M4"

"+ R całkowita energia bierna T1"

neither get's an error

Comment: I guess it's just something Excel missed while evaluating cell values. When you press F2 on those cells and press Enter, it will generate an error because just like other cells that begin with an operator, they're expected to be formula entries.